# Unity3d websocket+simplejson parsing doesn't work

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, websocket

I have the problem, that my while (loop) dosn't really work. Its a modified example from the free websocket asset for Unity3D. I can send json to my node.js server, but i can't receive the json. Obviously there must be something wrong with loop or with receiving of the string. Because my Debug.Log only plays once (only the first "while"). If I do an if reply == null, then I will receive a log again. So it seems there is no data arriving... But shouldn't my Loop working through and through, just only playing once?

Maybe you can help me out of my dilemma. Thank you very much! :)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using SimpleJSON;

public class EchoTest : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    IEnumerator Start () {
        WebSocket w = new WebSocket(new Uri("ws://localhost:8000/2"));
        yield return StartCoroutine(w.Connect());

        var N = new JSONClass();
        String P;
        N.Add("id", "unityclient");
        N.Add("to", "htmlclient");
        P = N.ToString();
        w.SendString(P);


        int i=0;
        while (true)
        {
            Debug.Log("while");
            string reply = w.RecvString();
            if (reply != null){
                Debug.Log("while2");
                var rep = JSON.Parse(reply);
                Debug.Log("jo");
                string jdata = rep["data"];
                Debug.Log(jdata);
                i++;
            }

            /*
            if (reply!="red"){
                Debug.Log ("Received: "+reply);
            }

            if (reply=="red"){
                var replydata = JSONNode.Parse(reply);
                var userid = replydata["data"]["userid"];
                var message = replydata["data"]["message"];
                Debug.Log(userid+":"+message);
            }

            if (reply == "red")
            {
                Debug.Log ("Received: "+reply);
                w.SendString("red back");
            }*/
            if (w.error != null)
            {
                Debug.LogError ("Error: "+w.error);
                break;
            }
            yield return 0;
        }
        w.Close();
    }
}
```

Maybe it helps to bring the node js server code:

```
// Websocket-Server
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer({host: 'localhost',port: 8000});


wss.on('connection', function(ws) 
{
    var clients = {};

    console.log('client verbunden...');


    ws.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log('von Client empfangen: '+data );
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);

          if("id" in obj) {
            // New client, add it to the id/client object
            clients[obj.id] = obj.id;
            console.log('client: ' + obj.id);
          } 
          else {
            // Send data to the client requested
            clients[obj.to].send(obj.data);
            console.log('send: ' + obj.data);
          }
    })
     /* ws.on('message', function(message) 
    {
        console.log('von Client empfangen: ' + message);
        ws.send('von Server empfangen: ' + message);
    });*/

});
```

Comment: try `yield return null;` instead of `yield return 0;` And question: Do you have error printed?

Comment: Also you can have in your Unity3D Console choosen to collapse same prints.

Comment: Oh, I am so silly. Yes, its collapsed! return null and return zero are the same results. But how can I catch the Json? No error, just Debug.Log("while").